# Speed up searches on large mysql table using indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a large MySQL table and when it had a low number of records the searches were fast, however the table now has over 400,000 records and searches take less than a second between 0.60 and 0.75. I've tried using indexes to bring this down to a nearer the 0.10 second or at least lower than 0.60 with no success. This estimate was from using `microtime` in PHP immediately before and after the SQL query.

This is a snippet of the table structure output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, there are other fields in the table but these aren't used in the SQL search statement.

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url_sha512hash` char(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no hash.',
  `viewdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq-web_url` (`url_sha512hash`),
  KEY `idx-viewdate` (`viewdate`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=404899 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

This is the SQL statement which takes between 60 and 75 seconds that I would like to speed up.

```
SELECT `id`, `url` FROM `mytable` USE INDEX(`idx-viewdate`)
  WHERE (`url` LIKE "https://www.domain.tld/path/to/dir"
   AND `viewdate` > "2022-11-20 23:23:00")
   OR (`url` LIKE "https://www.domain.tld/path/to/dir/" AND `viewdate` > "INSERT SAME VIEW DATE AS BEFORE")
  ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

Output from `EXPLAIN`

```
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                              |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | range | idx-viewdate  | idx-viewdate | 4       | NULL |   28 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: First thing, take MyISAM and *throw it in the trash*. There's no excuse to use that now. InnoDB can be tuned far, far better, having access to buffers and tuning parameters that MyISAM cannot, and will never be able to take advantage of.

Comment: A) `LIKE` is not great for performance if you're doing an "ends with" test. B) `OR` is not great for performance either, C) `ORDER BY` should be fine if there's an index that incorporates many of the elements, and D) Check with `EXPLAIN` where to start tuning.

Comment: Are you looking for exact URL matches? If so, I'd say use your hash-based index. MyISAM's implementation of `LONGTEXT` is truly awful, and will involve an absurd amount of disk seeking. If you're running on HDD or a slow SSD you're going to be in for a long wait, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Do your URL parameters actually have wild cards? If so, please include an example of the data being searched for and the parameters used.

Comment: @tadman Added output from `EXPLAIN`. Also yes looking for exact URL matches that are greater than a specific date.

Comment: @MatBailie By wildcards do you mean like percentage signs? if so there shouldn't be any, as any that happen to exist in the URLs should be encoded.

Comment: @AeroMaxx Please would you add a brief explanation, to your question, of what is being stored and how the search params are determined (why url or url + /)? What is the reason for the hash and the unique key on the hash?

Comment: What do you mean by "SAME URL AS BEFORE"?  Plug in real examples.  If the URL and date are the same, why have the OR?  Can there be wild cards at the _beginning_ of the URL?

Comment: Don't use `LIKE` unless you're doing approximate matches. Use `=` for exact matches. These can hit the index directly if you index properly.

Comment: @RickJames Done, although it wasn't so hard to know what that meant, as before that there was another URL.

Comment: @tadman - `LIKE` without any wildcards is optimized the same as `=`.  (But using `LIKE` does _imply_ that wildcards will be used.)

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

- Get rid of `id`; promote the hash to be the PK.
- Switch from `ORDER BY id` to `ORDER BY viewdate`
- Change from `OR` to `UNION`
- `url` REGEXP "INSERT SAME URL AS BEFORE/?" instead of OR.  Note the "?".
- I agree that you should switch to InnoDB; the suggestions here *depend on* that change.
- Since `REGEXP` is not optimized as well as `LIKE`, toss the `OR` and use

  ```
  WHERE URL LIKE   'blah%'
    AND URL REGEXP 'blah/?'
  ```

Putting them together...

Final query.  (Note `id` is gone)

**Plan A**

```
SELECT url, view_date
  FROM mytable
  WHERE view_date > '2022...'
    AND URL LIKE   'blah%'
    AND URL REGEXP 'blah/?'
  ORDER BY view_date DESC
```

and have

```
PRIMARY KEY(url_sha512hash)
INDEX(view_date, URL(191))
```

**Plan B**

Since you are really looking at two possible URLs, not lots, then

```
( SELECT id, url, view_date
      FROM mytable
      WHERE view_date > '2022...'
        AND url_sha512hash = sha256('blah')   -- w/0 slash
) UNION ALL
) SELECT id, url, view_date
      FROM mytable
      WHERE view_date > '2022...'
        AND url_sha512hash = sha256('blah/')   -- with slash
)
ORDER BY view_date DESC
```

together with

```
PRIMARY KEY(url_sha512hash, view_date)
```

**Plan C**

But even better is to remove the trailing "/" when `INSERTing` (at least for the hash) *and* when `SELECTing`.  (Or require the trailing "/" as suggested by MatBailie.)  Either way, there is only one thing to test:

```
SELECT id, url, view_date
      FROM mytable
      WHERE view_date > '2022...'
        AND url_sha512hash = sha256('blah')
ORDER BY view_date DESC
```

together with

```
PRIMARY KEY(url_sha512hash, view_date)
```

Plan C may get it down to 10ms on a spinning HDD or 1ms on SSD.  A and B might be half that fast.

If you need the `id` for other purposes, tack on

```
INDEX(id)   -- to keep `AUTO_INCREMENT` happy.
```

And, yes, convert the hex to `BINARY(nn)` with `UNHEX`.  (I did not incorporate such.)

Answer (score 1):

What version of MySQL are you running? Do you have control of the server or is it shared hosting?

The output from the following queries would be helpful for context -

```
SELECT VERSION();
ANALYZE TABLE `mytable`;
SHOW INDEX FROM `mytable`;
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mytable';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
```

The output of the following query will help with understanding the distribution your url data (may be slow so be cautious if server under load) -

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) countAll,
    COUNT(IF(LENGTH(url) <= 32, 1, NULL)) count32,
    COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(url, 32)) distinct32,
    COUNT(IF(LENGTH(url) <= 48, 1, NULL)) count48,
    COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(url, 48)) distinct48,
    COUNT(IF(LENGTH(url) <= 64, 1, NULL)) count64,
    COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(url, 64)) distinct64,
    COUNT(IF(LENGTH(url) <= 80, 1, NULL)) count80,
    COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(url, 80)) distinct80,
    COUNT(IF(LENGTH(url) <= 96, 1, NULL)) count96,
    COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(url, 96)) distinct96
FROM mytable;
```

As suggested by @MatBailie, you should add a composite index on url and viewdate, but do not include id.

When adding an index on TEXT/BLOB columns [you must specify the key length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-column-prefixes) (number of chars to be indexed). A longtext column can hold values up to 4GB, which would not be good for an index.

You also need to change the data type for your url column to a varchar. The current maximum length is 237 so bring it down to whatever you are happy with. 256 would give you some headroom but you may be more comfortable with 300.

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` 
    CHANGE COLUMN `url` `url` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    ADD INDEX `idx_url_viewed` (`url`(64), `viewdate`);
```

Please provide updated EXPLAIN output for your query, after applying the changes.

**UPDATE**

You are currently storing your hash in a multi-byte column which is relatively inefficient. I would suggest changing it to a binary column which will use less space and be more performant for index lookups.

```
# Add the binary column
ALTER TABLE `mytable`
    CHANGE COLUMN `url` `url` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    ADD COLUMN `url_bin_hash` BINARY(64);

# Populate it
UPDATE `mytable` SET `url_bin_hash` = UNHEX(`url_sha512hash`);

# Drop the old column, change the new one to NOT NULL, and add index
ALTER TABLE `mytable`
    DROP COLUMN `url_sha512hash`,
    CHANGE COLUMN `url_bin_hash` `url_bin_hash` BINARY(64) NOT NULL,
    ADD UNIQUE KEY `uq_url_bin_hash` (`url_bin_hash`);
```

Then, when inserting into the new binary hash you need to remember to -

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`url`, `url_bin_hash`, `viewdate`)
    VALUES ('url', UNHEX(SHA2('url', 512)), NOW());
```

And to search based on the new binary hash -

```
SELECT `id`, `url`
FROM `mytable`
WHERE `viewdate` > ?
AND `url_bin_hash` IN (UNHEX(SHA2(?, 512)), UNHEX(SHA2(CONCAT(?, '/'), 512)))
ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

Adding viewdate to the index on the binary hash column would be a waste of space as it is going to have to hit the clustered index to retrieve the url (and possibly other columns) anyway, unless you have a high miss-rate (queries returning 0 rows).

If the `id` column is not being used to reference `mytable` from elsewhere, you could ditch the surrogate PK and use the binary hash instead, as you already have a unique index on it.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(url)) FROM mytable;` before deciding on `VARHAR(nnn)`.

Comment: @RickJames I just checked and it's 237 at the moment.

Comment: @nnichols how big is BINARY(64) is that big enough for a sha512 hash?

Comment: @AeroMaxx - 237 - You could use `VARCHAR(255)` and get rid of the hash and its complexity.  64*8=512, so just right.

Comment: @AeroMaxx - you have not added any of the details I requested (they are important). Yes, BINARY(64) is the correct size. I have created a local test with 1M rows and the query returns in < 1ms. The biggest performance improvement (for your query) is simply changing the datatype for `url` and adding the index. Running your existing query against `url_sha512hash` instead of `url` should get you most of the way there as it already has the unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single index on `url, viewdate, id`.

- This will minimise the rows you Must search to find the matches.

As per comments, use InnoDB, not MyISAM.

Then use this `WHERE` clause...

```
WHERE
  viewdate > ?
  AND url IN (?, CONCAT(?,'/'))
```

`LIKE` is expensive, and unnecessary if you're looking for exact matches.

`IN()` is still more expensive than `=`, but this form makes it clear you're looking for one or two exact matches.

Finally, be VERY certain to use parameterises queries / prepared statements. Do NOT manually substitute strings in to your query using string manipulation in PHP.

***EDIT***

Or, put the hash column in the index, and hash the two forms of the URL parameters when searching.

```
ALTER TABLE `mysql` ADD INDEX `idx-visited2` (`url_sha512hash`, `viewdate`, `id`)
```

```
WHERE
  viewdate > DATE
  AND url_sha512hash IN (HASHED_URL, HASHED_URL_WITH_SLASH)
```

Comment: I tried to add the index as suggested but got an error.

```ALTER TABLE `mysql` ADD INDEX `idx-visited2` (`url`, `viewdate`, `id`);
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'url' used in key specification without a key length```

Comment: Infact, you'd be better off enforcing urls to end with `/` when you store the data. Then you can search for a single url, thst you can also enforce ending with `/`

Comment: Stop using MyISAM and or use VARCHAR(XXX) instead of TEXT

Comment: To do that I would need to check if the URL ended with a directory, or a filename before storing it in my database, some URLs contain a filename such as `contact.html` or `file.zip`.

Comment: Fine, then do that check. Ensure all URLs (both data and parameters) end with either a file name or a `/`, then the search is simpified. It's just data quality.

Comment: Or, put the hash column in the index, and hash the two forms of the URL parameters when searching.

Comment: I have converted the table to InnoDB, but still cant add the index mentioned above same error. Also the problem with VARCHAR is you have to specify a length and I don't know before hand how long the URLs will be, so some could be truncated.

Comment: Since converting to InnoDB the same query on MyISAM that took 0.60 to 0.75 seconds, takes so much longer! over 2 seconds per query.

Comment: @AeroMaxx When adding an index on TEXT/BLOB columns you have to specify the key length (number of chars to be indexed). A longtext column can hold values up to 4GB, which would not be good for your index. `ALTER TABLE mysql ADD INDEX idx_whatever (url(64), viewdate);`. You should do some analysis on your existing data to see how much of the url column needs to be indexed. What is the current max length for your url column? I would be surprised if you need more than VARCHAR(2048).

Comment: @nnichols I just checked and it's 237 at the moment.

Comment: ***Or, put the hash column in the index, and hash the two forms of the URL parameters when searching.***